# Windows Form DataGridView attach SelectedIndexChanged event to ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in Windows Form Application. There are two ComboBox columns in that DataGridView. On selection of some value in first ComboBox I would like to be able to populate second ComboBox. Here is the code:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
                comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= FirstComboSelectionChanged;
                comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += FirstComboSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    private void FirstComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        MessageBox.Show(sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString());
    }
```

It works well if I select some value from first ComboBox (first column of DataGridView), but after first column value selection if I then select some value from second ComboBox (second column of DataGridView) the event `FirstComboSelectionChanged` gets fired too (showing empty value)!!

It seems like the event gets also attached with second ComboBox too.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: It is just a simple bug, the combobox gets re-used to also edit column 2.  But you never unsubscribed the event so it just keeps firing.  You compounded the bug by showing the formatted value before it assigned.  There is no doubt a better way to do this but you only showed buggy code without any hint why you need this event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly your answer but is a simple solution.

You can use `dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event instead of `comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`event like this :

```
  void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```